# Where is the Service Reference in Universal App?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, service-reference, win-universal-app

Where is the Service Reference in Windows Phone Universal App ?

It seems that there is not. So my question is WHY ??

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shared project in a Universal app doesn't have an add reference since it doesn't compile to anything. For example a console project compiles to a .exe.

The build for the universal app will take the shared project a merge it into the projects that actually output something (Windows Store App or Windows Phone app).

Your add service reference and Nuget is on the Store App/Phone app level - if you add a reference there it will be accessible in your shared project (you may need to add it to both projects).